# Fixed Menu z-index is crashing with z-index Modal Backdrop

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass, styled-components

I have a modal backdrop with a zindex higher than the menu, the 2 are fixed but for some reason they are at the same level

[image]

Aside Menu Style

```
    export const Sidebar = styled("aside")<{ sidebarCollapse: boolean }>`
  grid-area: sidebar;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px 10px rgb(0 0 0 / 20%);
  display: grid;
  z-index: 3;
  width: 260px;
  max-width: ${({ sidebarCollapse }) => (sidebarCollapse ? "90px" : "260px")};
  overflow-x: ${({ sidebarCollapse }) =>
    sidebarCollapse ? "visible" : "hidden"};
  transition: max-width 0.4s ease-in-out;
  grid-template-rows: 95px 1fr;
  grid-row-gap: 23px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  position: fixed;
  margin-right: 200px;
`;
```

Modal BackDrop

```
    export const ModalBackdrop = styled("div")`
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 1040;
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh * 2);
  background-color: #000;
`;
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you check the z-index parents where ModalBackdrop is nested. It is probably set to be smaller than or equal to the SideBar. [Here's the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index)